# Target certain CSS Classes with Gridster Plugin

Tags: css, gridster

I'm using the [Gridster plugin](http://gridster.net/), where columns width are defined like this:

```
[data-sizex="12"] { width: ... }
[data-sizex="11"] { width: ... }
[data-sizex="10"] { width: ... }
....
```

I have 2 questions about this;

1. What kind of CSS classes are these? I have never done/seen anything like this, especially in CSS.
2. If I want to select all the columns from 1-12, how do I use the code? Typically I'm using something like `[class*=".."] this`. I don't think so I can get a format like this for the above scenario.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) These are [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors), to be specific these are **Attribute presence and value selectors**

2) If you want to select all the columns you don't have to use attribute selectors, just apply the CSS to the element. Well, for gridster plugin can replace `.grid` with `.gs_w {  }`, `.gs_w[data-sizex="12"]{ }` and so on in the demo jsfiddle.

```
.grid{
    /* Applies to all */
    background: #808080;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #eee; 
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

.grid[data-sizex="12"]{
    width: 720px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="11"]{
    width: 710px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="10"]{
    width: 700px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="9"]{
    width: 690px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="8"]{
    width: 680px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="7"]{
    width: 670px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="6"]{
    width: 660px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="5"]{
    width: 650px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="4"]{
    width: 640px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="3"]{
    width: 630px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="2"]{
    width: 620px;
}
.grid[data-sizex="1"]{
    width: 610px;
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6XVVP/)